# How can I display django form in modal window on homepage?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-modal, registration

The form works correctly in a register.html file but when I put inside the modal window on my home page the fields aren't displayed and the button doesn’t actually work.
My home.html file:

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% trans 'Блог страдальцев' %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-image";
     style="background-image: linear-gradient( 112.1deg,  rgba(32,38,57,1) 11.4%, rgba(63,76,119,1) 70.2% ); min-height: 100vh">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{% trans 'Блог страдальцев' %}</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">{% trans 'Главная' %}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">{% trans 'О блоге страдальцев' %}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                               data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                {% trans 'Разделы блога' %}
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/pozn">{% trans 'Страдальческий' %}</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/len">{% trans 'Не страдальческий' %}</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/superlren">{% trans 'Очень страшно' %}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
                          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                        </form>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                      Окошечко
                    </button>
                    <!-- Модальное окно -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Окошечко</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            ????
                        <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="{{ 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reg/' }}" ></iframe>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                       <a href="{% url 'register'  %}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Регистрация' %}</button>
                    </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'login'  %}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Авторизация' %}</button>
                    </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'postnumber'  %}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans '' %}</button>
                    </a>
{#                        <a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>#}
                    </ul>
                    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
                            <select name="language">
                                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                {% for language in languages %}
                                    <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                                    </option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Установить' %}" />
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    {% block content %}
        {% for post in object_list %}
            <div style="margin-top: 1%">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row align-items-start">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="bg-image card shadow-1-strong"
                                 style="background-image: radial-gradient( circle 369px at -2.9% 12.9%,  rgba(247,234,163,1) 0%, rgba(236,180,238,0.56) 46.4%, rgba(163,203,247,1) 100.7% );">
                                <div class="card-body text-white">
                                    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                    <a href="{% url 'profile_page' post.author.username %}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Автор:' %} {{ post.author }}</button>
                                    </a>
                                    <p>{% trans 'Автор поста:' %} <b>{{ post.author }}</b></p>
                                    <p> Категория: {{ post.group }}</p>
                                    <p>{{ post.body|truncatechars:1000 }}</p>
                                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Подробнее' %}</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock content %}
    <nav class="list-pages">
    <ul>
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">{% trans "Назад" %}</a>
        </button>
        {% endif %}
        {% for p in paginator.page_range %}
                   {% if page_obj.number == p %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">{{ p }}</button>
                   {% else %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
            <a href="?page={{ p }}">{{ p }}</a>
        </button>
                   {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
         <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">{% trans "Вперед" %}</a>
        </button>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav></center>
<p> Количество постов: {{ paginator.count }}</p>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py:

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    conf_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py:

```
class Bloglist(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = NewUserForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user:
            login(self.request, user)

        return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)



def my_view(request):
    form = NewUserForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)

forms.py:
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    model = NewUser
    fields = ("username", "password1", "password2")

register.html:
{%extends 'home.html'%}

{%block content%}

    <div class="center">

      <form id="htmx-dialog-form" method="post" novalidate class="card">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="text-center">Create your account</h2>
        {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <small class="error">{{ field.errors|striptags  }}</small>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary full-width">
        <hr>
        <p class="text-center">Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login'%}">Login Here</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{%endblock content%}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('about/', AboutPageView .as_view(), name='about'),
    path('', Bloglist.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', profile, name='profile_page'),
    path('user/registration/', registration, name='signup'),
    path('post/profile/<str:username>/', sign_inf, name='signup_info'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path("pozn/", raz1.as_view(), name='raz1.html'),
    path("len/", raz2.as_view(), name='raz2.html'),
    path("superlren/", raz3.as_view(), name='raz3.html'),
    path('postsnum/', postcount, name='postnumber'),
    path('reg/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('', RegisterView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

I tried putting content of register.html to home.html but it didn't help. I am not sure how to change views and other files to make the usercreatio form appear in home.html file inside modal window

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you guys